# Batch Scripting- Wild Cards in 'If Statements'

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I am writing a Batch script wherein I need to use a wild card in an `if` statement to match a variable against a string. If it matches, the program will go further.

```
if "!_var!"=="str*" (

-- SOME COMMANDS --

)
```

This is the syntax I have used, but I found that it is not working out at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo %var% |findstr /b "str" >nul && (
  echo yes
  some more commands
) || (
  echo no
  some more commands
)
```

looks for  (`/b`= at the beginning) `str`, (don't write to screen `>nul`) , if found (`&&`) do something, if not found (`||`) do another thing.

You can also add a `/i` to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

`IF` doesn't support pattern matching but you can extract the first three characters from the variable's value and compare it to `str`.

The syntax for substring extraction is this:

```
%variable:~offset,length%
```

and similarly for delayed expansion:

```
!variable:~offset,length!
```

So, in your case it would be:

```
IF "!_var:~0,3!" == "str" (
  ...
)
```